# Angular2 how do you listen for changes to data in a class?

Tags: angular

I have an array containing class User. This array is presented through an `*ngFor` as repeated `<li>` items. The user can click on these items and get the detail for a user in a detail control.

The fields in the detail control are bound using `[(ngModel)]`.

I am trying to figure out how to detect when a user has changed the data in a particular user so that I can mark it dirty and only send modified users back to the web service. I would also like to stop the user from navigating away with unsaved data.

In C# I would use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to accomplish this.

I have been looking at the `ngOnChanges` and `onchange` but these don't seem to be what I am looking for.

Any assistance would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `<form>` for the input fields where you edit the user, than the form provides the information whether something was changed.

Comment: How do you listen for those changes in the form?

Comment: Depends on how your form looks like. Something like `this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(...)` as far as I remember.